# Can I include a standalone class in class diagram?

Tags: uml, associations, class-diagram, class-design

I have a class diagram of my system that I made, the problem is I have a class that doesn't have any relation to another class inside the ecosystem. The full diagram that I've already made is like this:

[image]

Is it possible to have this kind of class diagram, where there is one standalone class there, and also two classes (ProgoProject-ProgoDocument) with relation but no relation to other?

Comment: Well, it depends. What do YOU think?

Comment: Why do you need this class? Having a class that is not linked to any other class is very unlikely (not impossible though). Usually though it is a result of a poor design.

Comment: Are you sure your standalone class is *really* standalone? I see it has a project_id. Often that means there really should be an association to Project instead.

Comment: @Ister why should unrelated domain classes be associated?  Why would it be better to couple all the classes with another one? what about domain models vs. solution models? Are associations the only way classes can inteact with each other? Is there any research paper that could link the quality of the design to the number of associated/unassiciated classes?  (sorry for all these questions, but your comment teased my curiosity) ;-)

Comment: And 5 of your classes repeat a set of file related attribute (file_name, file_size,...). I'm sure there's room for improvement there by moving these shared attributes to a common class. (possibly with a generalization, else else with an asssocation. But I don't know which without understanding the class names)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can have disconnected classes in a class diagram:

- Classes are not obliged to be associated with other classes. Standalone classes, or islands of classes without associations to other islands are very common.
- Objects of one class can interact with other objects, including of other classes, even without being associated. This is possible via multiple ways, for example when the operation of one object is called with an other object as argument; or if some global objects (or transient local objects within an operation) are known to others.

*By the way: some people analyse some more [metrics](https://www.aivosto.com/project/help/pm-oo-ck.html) in UML models for assessing complexity of a design and risks (e.g. this [article](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/1022494.1022523))*